# Accordion scrolls page too low after clicking on the title

Tags: jquery, css, html

**Intro**
usually I trying to solve my problems at the code by myself, but with this one I need your help. I would like to say, that I tried all the solutions that looks similar, but I am not very experienced coder, so I failed.

So, I have a custom code for the *custom accordion* that show information about the site/products for mobile users in that accordion style. You can see how it look [here](https://www.onkoklinika.lv/onkoklinika-mobila-lapa/) and code in fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/maxmiko/3qsrdhwL/5/)

**Question/Problem**

It is multi-level (nested) accordion and each accordion box contains a lot of text. There are additional divs with content under this accordion. Problem is, if viewer reads content from one accordion box and wants to open another it scrolls all thing too far during the page. I want to clarify - accordion works well itself - the main problem - it is sends viewer too far down during the page, but I need that he sees the element he clicked at the top of the page.

**Example**

1. You click: "Par Kliniku" - "Par Kliniku" and "Mūsu Komanda" is appearing
2. You choose: "MŪsu Komanda" - you scroll down and see "Ginekologija"
3. You click "Ginekologija" and all the things goes too down. This is my problem.

Comment: WPSE is good for questions that are specific to WordPress development issues. Generic HTML/CSS/JavaScript questions are better suitable for [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com). Please read [the topics here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/asking) to know how to ask a good question in WPSE.